# how to write a future that wait for an event

Tags: multithreading, events, scala, rpc, future

I have a client/server socket that does some rpc things. I know a bit about finagle and I find the isolation with a Future very elegant. So my question would be how to write a Future in scala that wait for an event (the server reply of my client request). The implementation would probably use identified request but what I lack is the way to ask the future to wait for the event without a busy wait.

Answer (score 2):

Create a `Promise` instead of `Future` and add a listener to your event which fulfills the promise. Return the promise's future to your client (in Twitter Util future library it's the promise itself, in Scala 2.10 it's [`p.future`](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/futures-promises.html#promises)).

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you need to take a look at [Akka Actors](http://akka.io/)

Here is example of an actor

```
class MyActor extends Actor {
   val log = Logging(context.system, this)
   def receive = {
      case "test" ⇒ log.info("received test")
      case _      ⇒ log.info("received unknown message")
   }
}
```